# How to prevent a row from being deleted based on the value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose we have a table called `StudentAccount` with columns `SID` (student Id) and `AmountOwing`.
We cannot delete the account from the system unless the student owes nothing on their account. (That is `AmountOwing = $0.00`).

For example the table could look like:

```
SID    | Amount Owing
-------+--------------
32415  | $30.00
39872  | $0.00
35135  | $3200.00
```

In this case, we can delete row 2 only.

Is there a way to enforce this constraint on the table using valid MS SQL Server 2012 SQL syntax (so that an uneducated user won't accidentally delete a non-empty account)?

Comment: I think you need to use a `before delete` trigger to implement this.

Comment: use a before delete trigger checking the value if not 0 cancel the delete action, however cascade deletes can't be enabled for this to work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: @xQbert What do you mean by cascade deletes can't be enabled? You mean some other table can't cascade delete the table I want to put a trigger on? Or the table I want to put a trigger on can't cascade delete other tables? Or no cascade deletes in the whole database?

Comment: From link listed: For INSTEAD OF triggers, the DELETE option is not allowed on tables that have a referential relationship specifying a cascade action ON DELETE. Similarly, the UPDATE option is not allowed on tables that have a referential relationship specifying a cascade action ON UPDATE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgD_StudentAccount_Delete
ON dbo.StudentAccount
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    deleted d
        WHERE   d.AmountOwing <> 0
    )
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RAISERROR('Delete error: there are students with Amount <> 0', 16, 1);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DELETE  StudentAccount 
        WHERE   EXISTS( SELECT * FROM deleted d WHERE d.[SID] = StudentAccount.[SID] )
    END
END
```

Answer (score -2):

Suggesting that you have AmountOwing as a number value (int, float, ...)

```
DELETE
FROM StudentAccount
WHERE AmountOwing > 0
```

Or work with a trigger (so that user should not delete any)

```
CREATE TRIGGER DML_ON_TABLEA
   ON  StudentAccount
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CASE 
    WHEN (AmountOwing = 0) THEN
        -- DELETE STATEMENT 
    END
END
GO
```